# Adding JSONObject.KeySet() to a Mutable Set in scala

Tags: json, scala, collections

I am new to scala. I am working with some JSON objects and would like to get a set of all the keys available in the JSON Objects. I am trying to do something like this:

```
var set = scala.collection.mutable.Set[String]()
for(condition) {    
  set ++= jsonObject.keySet().asInstanceOf[Set[String]]
}
```

when I run the code, I get the following error:

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: java.util.HashMap$KeySet cannot be cast to scala.collection.mutable.Set
```

The error speaks for itself. 
I also tried writing the keys to a file:

```
json2.keySet().toArray().foreach { x => keysWriter.write(x) }
```

The IDE gives an error saying: `overloaded method value write with alternatives: (x$1: Int)Unit <and> (x$1: String)Unit <and> (x$1: Array[Char])Unit cannot be applied to (Object)`

So, what would be a better approach to get an accessible list of keys ?

Any help would be appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You could use [`JavaConverters`](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.12.3/scala/collection/JavaConverters$.html):

```
import scala.collection.JavaConverters._

val keys = jsonObject.keySet.asScala
```

`keys` is a `scala.collection.mutable.Set`. To create an immutable Scala `Set`, do this instead:

```
val keys = jsonObject.keySet.asScala.toSet
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I was able to do something like this: `json.keySet().asScala.foreach { x => set.add(x) }`. It works fine now. Please add this to your answer and I'll accept it.